# unable to change the screen resolution

Tags: 11.10, resolution, screen, vmware

I am unable to change the screen resolution. My PC is ASUS M/B and using onboard graphics. I installed the Ubuntu 11.10 thru VMware player. In the appearance window it is showing a resolution of 1920 x 1280 and I need to use mouse to cover various corners of screen. I tried to change the resolution but to no avail. Please tell me how to change resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Please use Virtualbox(www.virtualbox.org).It has lot of more features.Also Install the Extension Pack.

In VMware Player you can resize the program window.